# Scala metals: "Evaluation failed because the thread is not suspended."

Tags: scala, scala-metals

So, like the title says, this error comes up as I run the program. However, should I compile the code in any other IDE (tested IntelliJ and it works) or through terminal, it works. How can this be solved?

I have seen other threads, and they seem to suggest that I abandon vs code, but I'd really not want to as it is lightweight and rather fast (does another IDE like this exist?). So, I'd really love a solution to this issue...

Comment: I would recommend asking in the **metals** channel in **discord**: https://discord.gg/3eHeFJ2XhJ

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Fair enough. Would it be okay to ask a question irrelevant to the topic? If so, here it is: would it be possible to create a dialog box, like in java (JOptionPane)? I have tried, but Scala does not know what "frame" is, when setting it up.